# MongoDB Unique 10 digit ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I would like to create a unique 10 digit ID in MongoDB - for every user under a particular client that we get in our system. Note that we store all of our users (who are from different clients), under the same collection. The ID needs to be unique only among users of same client. Two users from two different clients, can share the same ID, even though they exist in the same collection.

Any suggestions on how this 10 digit id can be unique for every user.

Comment: How about using the id already in your collection?

Comment: I would definitely use the `_id` field from the collection.

Comment: Yes, but the id in my collection is 24 chars and I need a 10 digit unique id

Answer (score 1):

`mongoid_token` looks like it can do what you need:

https://github.com/thetron/mongoid_token

Comment: This will work, however, this is a unique token across the collection. I would like to have a unique id for every user under the same client, however, the users under different clients, can share the same id. Note: All the users (from various clients) are under one collection. So I need a unique id only for each subcollection